# ViterbiParser and ChartParser returning None for PCFG in NLTK

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, viterbi

I'm trying to use ViterbiParser and ChartParser to parse the sentence "Birds fly."  Tracing the process, it seems like it should be working, but always returns `None`

Here are the traces.
(Viterbi):

```
Inserting tokens into the most likely constituents table...
  Insert: |=.| Birds
  Insert: |.=| fly
Finding the most likely constituents spanning 1 text elements...
  Insert: |=.| NNS -> 'Birds' [1.0]
  Insert: |=.| NP -> NNS [0.206897]
  Insert: |.=| VB -> 'fly' [1.0]
  Insert: |.=| VP -> VB [0.21875]
Finding the most likely constituents spanning 2 text elements...
  Insert: |==| S -> NP VP [1.0]
```

ChartParser:

```
|.     Birds     .      fly      .|
Leaf Init Rule:
|[---------------]               .| [0:1] 'Birds'
|.               [---------------]| [1:2] 'fly'
Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
|[---------------]               .| [0:1] NNS -> 'Birds' *
Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
|[---------------]               .| [0:1] NP -> NNS *
Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
|[--------------->               .| [0:1] NP -> NP * NP
|[--------------->               .| [0:1] S  -> NP * VP
Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
|.               [---------------]| [1:2] VB -> 'fly' *
Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
|.               [---------------]| [1:2] VP -> VB *
|.               [--------------->| [1:2] VP -> VB * VP
|.               [--------------->| [1:2] VP -> VB * ADJP
|.               [--------------->| [1:2] VP -> VB * PP
Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
|.               [--------------->| [1:2] VP -> VP * PP
|.               [--------------->| [1:2] VP -> VP * NP
|.               [--------------->| [1:2] VP -> VP * VP
Single Edge Fundamental Rule:
|[===============================]| [0:2] S  -> NP VP *
```

Both parsers seem to build the sentence correctly, but still return None.  What's going on?

Comment: So, do you think there's a bug in the library code, or do you suspect there's an error in your code which uses NLTK? If the latter is the case, how do you expect us to help you without providing any code?

Comment: After working on this for hours, I actually found the problem.  I'm using a PCFG grammar.  The first rule loaded in the grammar needs to have the left hand side set as the start state for the grammar.  There is no clear way to override it.  I changed the order of my grammar rules and it's now working.

Comment: Good to hear! Consider answering your own question. It might help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

After working on this for hours, I actually found the problem. I'm using a PCFG grammar. The first rule loaded in the grammar needs to have the left hand side set as the start state for the grammar. There is no clear way to override it. I changed the order of my grammar rules and it's now working.

The exact reason for the problem...  The PCFG is trying to come up with an arrangement of rules that creates a tree rooted at the "start state".  In my case it's "S" (for sentence) I had loaded the rules out of order, so it was trying to get to a noun phrase, and therefore couldn't come up with a tree that worked.